# ADMIN SDK not accessing group

Tags: google-apps-script

AdminDirectory fail to access my group

I have turned ON Admin Directory API in advanced google services under the project.
I have enabled Admin SDK under ADMIN console security settings

```
var NewMail = "john.doe@gmail.com";
var NewMember = 
    {
     email: NewMail,
     role: 'MEMBER'
    };
var MemberExist = false;
var pageToken, page;
var groupEmail = 'israelmotorcycleclub@googlegroups.com';
var groupDomainName = 'googlegroups.com';
AdminDirectory.Members.insert(NewMember, groupEmail);
```

As in the past, I expected on first run, to get a message directing me to the API key authorization, but Im not getting it.